# Socket based PrintWriter doesn't flush, just after close()

Tags: java, sockets, flush, printwriter

I am writing a server-client application.

The problem is, that in the server the `PrintWriter` doesn't flush after some point, just after I close the print writer.  But if I close the print writer, it closes the socket as well, however I need to use it later.

How can I solve this?

```
pw = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
pw.println("igyulibigyuli");
pw.flush();
```

It doesn't flush, just if I close the printwriter after the flush.(Or if I close the program!)

Comment: You're trying to `flush` the `PrintWriter` after closing it?

Comment: No, I meant that the client gets datas successfully before this problem occures at some point of the program.

Comment: You might call `flush()` explicitly.

Comment: I did it, however I set it to autoflush.

Comment: Oh, I am idiot.

The problem was that on the client side, I was reading in using a loop cheching only if there are null value.
Of course, if I closed the socket on the server, the client got an exception that closed the loop, thats why I thought that the printwriter was not flushing.

Comment: If you figured out your issue, cancel the question please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problam was that the socket was busy reading(in a while loop, till it get not null).